# Port forwarding

Tags: networking, port

I have a simple requirement of hosting a webserver on my computer. But unfortunately, the internet connection provided by my employer has only ports 21 & 80 open. Rest of all the ports are closed. I tried port forwarding for ports 80 and 21 but they are already in use by my employer itself. So, is there any other way of hosting a webserver on my computer?

P.S.: I am on linux with Apache.

Comment: If you have as requirement to have a web-server running on a custom port, shouldn't your employer want to open that port for you? Or are trying to run a web-server without them knowing about it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Thanks for the suggestions. I am trying to run it without my employer knowing about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the firewall run an HTTP proxy, or is it just a simple port forwarder? If it's a proxy, it may be able to forward to different internal IPs based on the `Host:` header, similar to the way virtual web hosts operate.

If not, you won't be able to use these ports. A NAT router can forward a port to only one IP. If hosting the webserver is a job requirement, as you say, you should be able to contact the network administrator and get another port opened for it. If they won't do it on your request, your manager should be able to confirm the requirement.

Comment: I am able to connect to the Internet via a HTTP proxy. Can you explain how to forward based on the Host header. Even a link would do.

Comment: This is something the firewall admininistrator will have to do. It should be in the firewall's documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I will take it up with the admin.